# Google Map V3 - Displaying markers from XML feed

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have an XML feed of marker data that I want to plot on a Google map.  The XML data I have is in this format:

```
<markers>
<marker  uid="2" filesUploaded="" lat="101.00000000000" lng="112.00000000000"/>
<marker  uid="2" filesUploaded="" lat="132.00000000000" lng="112.00000000000"/>
<marker  uid="2" filesUploaded="" lat="143.00000000000" lng="111.00000000000"/>
<marker  uid="2" filesUploaded="" lat="134.00000000000" lng="112.00000000000"/>
</markers>
```

I had this working in V2 but am not sure for V3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample with the v3 API: http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/xmlparsing/

Answer (score 0):

First of [parse the xml](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp) and for each marker in your xml [create a marker](http://code.google.com/intl/el-GR/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#Markers)